# "Function expected" error when updating frames with javascript in IE9

Tags: javascript

We're using some javascript to update a child frame. This has been working fine in IE7 and IE8 but only works in IE9 when compatibility mode is switched on. I've added the code fragment below. I've tried various solutions including using window instead document but nothing seems to work. The error "Function expected" is always given.

Any help be would much appreciated!
Thanks, Andrew

```
 <script language="jscript">
 function UpdateContent(strAddress) {
       document.frames("content").document.location.replace(strAddress);
                    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`document.frames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a non-standard (possibly inexistent) collection.

To read the collection of IFrames, use square brackets and `window.frames`. Also, remove `language="jscript"`, or replace it with `language="javascript"`.

```
frames["content"].document.location.replace(strAddress);
```

Comment: No need for the `document` in that example. `location` is a property of the Window object.